# How to pass on value from python file into IF statement in html using jinja?

Tags: html, python-3.x, variables, if-statement, jinja2

Issue:

In python I want to return html file with a parameter empty

```
return render_template("index.html", empty = "No")
```

In index.html

```
{% block main %}
    {% if {{ empty }} == "No" %}
             // TODO Somethig
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

As a response I get

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ':', got '}'
```

How is it possible to implement this idea?

Any help is greatly appreciated ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix:
you want `{% if empty == "No" %}` instead of `{% if {{ empty }} == "No" %}`

Your code would be:

```
{% block main %}
    {% if empty == "No" %}
             // TODO Somethig
        <p>NOOO</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Easy fix indeed